# Excel 2010 - Structured references not showing up in formulas

Tags: excel-formula, pivot-table, excel-2010

I'm having some trouble using structured references in formulas and I can't work out why it's not working.

I have two data connections, each importing a csv file into my workbook. Both imports are showing as named ranges:

[image: Name Manager]

When I Ctrl+A the MasterTeams sheet, the name also shows up in the name box:

[image: Name Box]

But when I try to reference the ranges in a formula, it doesn't pick either of them up as it should:

[image: Formula]

And I can't use either range as a reference for a new pivot table:

[image: Pivot]

This is causing me issues as both data sets will change over time and I need my pivots and formulas to adapt as needed.

'Use table names in formulas' is ticked and was ticked before I made the data connections. I have other workbooks, not made by me, with working structured references but I can't see any difference with the way they're set up.

I've Googled around all day but can't seem to find a solution to this one. It's like Excel is just refusing to recognise my tables.